# PCA and K-means for word clustering

Tags: python, nltk, cluster-analysis, k-means, pca

I have a corpus of Wikipedia articles. I identified the 10,000 most frequent words, found their Word2Vec vectors, and used spherical k-means on the vectors to cluster the words into 500 groups based on similarity in meaning.

I picked out 3 of the clusters of words and converted the words back to their word vectors. Each word vector is an array of 300 values, so I applied PCA (from sklearn) on all of them to convert them to 2D. Then I plotted:

[image: plot of 3 clusters]

Each dot represents a word, each color represents 1 cluster. The problem is, these clusters should not be overlapping. One cluster has computer-related words, another cluster has racial-related words, and the last cluster has relationship-related words. I added the word "chicken" to the cluster with computer words, but when plotted, its dot was right next to the dot for "keyboard."

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. Is there anything wrong with my approach? Here's my PCA code:

```
for words in theList: #theList is an array of my 3 clusters
    lexicalUnitVectors = load_bin_vec("GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", words) #convert words to Word2Vec vectors
    lexicalUnitVectors = list(lexicalUnitVectors.values())
    lexicalUnitVectors = pca.fit(lexicalUnitVectors).transform(lexicalUnitVectors) #apply pca
    print(lexicalUnitVectors) #this shows a bunch of 2D points; all x and y values are close to 0 for some reason
    xs = [i*1 for i in lexicalUnitVectors[:, 0]] #ignore this
    ys = [i*1 for i in lexicalUnitVectors[:, 1]] #ignore this
    plt.scatter(xs, ys, marker = 'o')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Typically I think you should apply PCA before you do the clustering. That's the point of the PCA, to reduce dimensionality so you can cluster on only unique aspects.

2) I don't know if I agree with your idea that the first two eigenvectors necessarily need to be separated - there are many eigenvectors that are important to each cluster if your dimensionality is reduced from words. How many eigenvectors are you keeping? Typically you only keep such that you're explaining ~90% of the variability in the data, but you should play around with this.